# Retrieve only the Value without the Key in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to retrieve only the "second" value of a child from my firebase database.
The structure looks like this:

[image: The database Structure]

And what I'm getting as an output is this:

[image: What my output is]

However what I actually want is just:

**someURL.com**

Ideally even without the https or http (where I probably need an if to check, since it is not known for all of them in advance). I guess there are 2 options, either unwrapping the string in Swift, or (what I was hoping for) just retrieving the actual value without the brackets and "url" in the beginning. I couldn't find a similar problem on here yet.

My code for retrieving:

```
dataSource?.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
        let snap = obj as! FIRDataSnapshot


        let childString = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

        cell.textLabel?.text = String(childString)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
dataSource?.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
        let snap = obj as! FIRDataSnapshot


        let childString = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

        if let url = childString["url"] as? String {
            cell.textLabel?.text = url
        } else {
            print("No value for url")
        }
    }
```

childString variable you are using is a dictionary which has values for keys. You need to fetch the value for the key "url".

Comment: It gives me an error, that childString doesn't have the valueForKey member. Value of type '[String : AnyObject]' has no member 'valueForKey'